# Google automated search query thresholds

Tags: ruby

I wrote a Ruby script that automates some web searching I need to do - I have a list of like 40 search criteria I need to google for dozens of cities.

I'm trying to Google to figure out how many search queries Google will permit per day, as well as per second, so I can put a delay in my code if I need to but am finding some sources that say 100 queries per day and saw another source said 1000.

Does anybody know what thresholds will trigger Google's software that detects automated search queries?

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66357?hl=en

Comment: I would guess that is something that Google does not make public as they don't want people to easily get around it by putting in a delay to the automated query. Your best bet will be to contact Google and see what they require to use automated queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your answer is on the link you provided:

> Google's Terms of Service do not allow the sending of automated queries of any sort to our system without express permission in advance from Google.

Comment: Obviously, but who cares.  I'm not trying to do anything malicious and it appears all the good API's for this sort of thing are now deprecated.  I suppose I will just send them a message on gmail, right, and wait for them to respond to me.

Comment: If they clearly state that they don't allow unsolicited automated queries, one could logically deduce that there isn't a published or publicly-known limit for said unsolicited queries.